# Logging EJB RMI invocations

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi

Is there something analogous to a RequestListener that I can use for an RMI invocation?  Is there some way I can inject context info into the log4j MDC when an EJB is loaded via an RMI call?

I have a web app with all the business logic implemented via EJBs.  My EJBs use Log4j to create log entries.

In a request listener, I have added some specific paramteres to the Log4j MDC (such as a request id, session id, etc) that are inserted automatically by the appender.

```
public class Log4jMDCRequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {
    /**
     * Inject the necessary trackers into the MDC to use in the log4j loggers
     */
    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent paramServletRequestEvent) {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) paramServletRequestEvent.getServletRequest();

        // generate a random requestId to correlate all logs from the same request
        String requestId = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(32);
        MDCUtils.setRequestId(requestId);

        // inject the username and ip into the MDC as well for use in some logs
        MDCUtils.setUsername(RequestUtils.getLoginUserName(request));
        MDCUtils.setIP(RequestUtils.getRealIP(request));
    }
}
```

log4j.xml:

```
 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %X{requestId} [%c] %X{username} %X{ip} %m%n"/>
 </layout>
```

This works great for all web/request based requests (since the RequestListener fires for every request)

However, whenever my EJB is invoked via an RMI invocation from a different server/service, the logs are obviously missing the requestId, username, IP.

Is there something analogous to a RequestListener that I can use for an RMI invocation where I can extract the IP of the calling server, etc?

Comment: The most portable way would be to use a `@javax.ejb.AroundInvoke` Interceptor. Other methods are app-server specific.

Comment: @eckes that's what I was thinking as well.  I presume I'll be able to extract caller metadata from the context object in the invoker then?

Comment: Hm, good question. I know the MessageContext of JAX-WS is present, not sure about RMI (or JBoss Remoting).

Comment: @eckes I ran a test today and I don't see any way to extract the caller metadata from the InvocationContext object.  The only thing I find is a `getContextData()` method, but that returns an empty map.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I guess that means app server specific methods.